# Variadic templates in C++ and a comma separated string

Tags: c++, templates, csv, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am trying to wrap my head around variadic templates and figured that a simple function which should take arbitrary arguments (of different types) would be a good exercise.

**First Try**

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::string>::type
concater ( T x ) { return std::to_string(x); }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::string>::type
concater ( T x ) { return std::to_string(x); }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T,std::string>::value, std::string>::type
concater ( T x ) { return std::string(x); }

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::string>::type
concater ( T x, Rest... xs ) { return std::to_string(x) + "; " + concater( xs... ); }

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::string>::type
concater ( T x, Rest... xs ) { return std::to_string(x) + "; " + concater( xs... ); }

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T,std::string>::value, std::string>::type
concater ( T x, Rest... xs ) { return std::string(x) + "; " + concater( xs... ); }

template<typename... Values>
std::string to_csv ( Values... vs )
{
    return concater( vs... );
}
```

Well it works, but it's not nice. Also it probably would not generalize to other types. So I made a second attempt and figured using the `<<` operator would make the function more general.

**Second Try**

```
template<typename Stream, typename T>
void concat2 ( Stream & s, T x ) { s << x; }

template<typename Stream, typename T, typename... Rest>
void concat2 ( Stream & s, T x, Rest... xs )
{
    s << x << ";";
    concat2( s, xs... );
}

template<typename... Values>
std::string to_csv2 ( Values... vs )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    concat2( oss, vs... );
    return oss.str();
}
```

This is shorter and looks nicer in my opinion. But it still seems off by a little bit. How would you approach this task or is there a way to make this even nicer?

I am also wondering if this:

```
std::cout << to_csv(1,"Hello",3) << std::endl;
```

would get compiled to something similar to this:

```
std::cout << 1 << "Hello" << 3 << std::endl;
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Side note; If you want valid CSV, be aware of strings containing " and/or ; (your separator)

Comment: You may get further on http://codereview.stackexchange.com for "make this [working code] nicer" type questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again, pack expansion inside a *braced-init-list* comes to the rescue.

```
template<typename Value, typename... Values>
std::string to_csv2 ( Value v, Values... vs )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    using expander = int[];
    oss << v; // first
    (void) expander{ 0, (oss << ";" << vs, void(), 0)... };
    return oss.str();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17de1d94c52f2156).

The idea is to print the first element first; then print the remaining elements, each preceded by the separator, in a single pack expansion. We expand the pattern `(oss << ";" << vs, void(), 0)` in the initializer list for a temporary array, so that given `vs` as a pack containing `v1, v2, v3` it expands to

```
(void) expander{ 0, (oss << ";" << v1, void(), 0),
                    (oss << ";" << v2, void(), 0),
                    (oss << ";" << v3, void(), 0) };
```

The commas inside the parentheses are comma operators, which evaluate the left operand, discard the result, and then evaluate the right operand. The `void()` protects against any comma operator overloads that may exist (since we don't know the type of the values and what `oss << vs` might return).

Each of those expressions evaluates to 0, the rightmost operand of the comma operator, which is used to initialize an element in the temporary array that we don't actually care about. The first 0 is required to ensure that we don't make an illegal zero-size array if `vs` is an empty pack.

The net result is that evaluating each initializer-clause will output the corresponding variable preceded by the separator to the stream, and there's a strict guarantee in the standard that those initializer-clauses are evaluated left-to-right, so we will have the values sent to the stream in the right order.

Comment: I have seen that syntax a couple of times before, but how does it actually work? Since `expander` is an `int` array, is the `void()` actually necessary, or could you use `{0, (oss << vs, 0)...}` instead? That explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: Based on an example in [this documentation](http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/docs/cppreference-doc-20130729/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack.html), it seems this would also work: `expander{ (oss << vs, 0)... };`  or even: `int expander[sizeof...(vs)] = { (oss << vs, 0)... };`
`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That doesn't work if `vs` is an empty pack, or if `vs` is some custom type such that `oss << vs` returns something that overloads the comma operator.

Comment: Wouldn't using `sizeof()` address the empty pack issue? So `int expander[sizeof...(vs)] = { (oss << vs, 0)... };` would expand to `int expander[0] = {};` instead of `int expander[] = {};`, isn't that valid?

Comment: @RemyLebeau zero-sized arrays are not legal.  Though `std::initializer_list<int>` in the place of `int[]` should work.

Comment: That is very interesting! Now I need to wrap my head around yet another thing. :) The rightmost 0 is needed because expander refers to an integer array, right?

Comment: @j.dog Right, it's an array of ints, so each initializer has to produce an int.

Answer (score 3):

The second chunk of code is pretty much the pattern I use whenever dealing with recursive variadic templates. You absolutely **must** have a variadic template that strips off parameters, and another template that takes a static number of parameters that gets called once the variadic template runs out of extra parameters. It's also often nice to have an additional function to neatly wrap the functionality in a bow like you have, especially in cases where the compiler has issues with automatic parameter type deduction.

In regards to your second question:

```
std::cout << to_csv(1,"Hello",3) << std::endl;
```

would be the equivalent of

```
void concat ( Stream & s, int x ) { s << x; }

void concat ( Stream & s, std::string x, int y )
{
    s << x << ";";
    concat( s, y );
}

void concat ( Stream & s, int x, std::string y, int z )
{
    s << x << ";";
    concat( s, y, z );
}

std::string to_csv ( int x, std::string y, int z )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    concat( oss, x, y, z );
    return oss.str();
}
//...
std::cout << to_csv(1,"Hello",3) << std::endl;
```

It's important to note the fact that your variadic template usage is generating all those functions. While this often has little runtime impact when you compile your code with an aggressively optimizing compiler for release, it can cause some serious slowdown in debug builds.

Comment: While recursion is an important and useful technique in dealing with variadic templates, it's not required in every case.

Comment: It definitely depends on the usage, yes. I will clarify my intent.

Comment: @T.C.: recursion is required in *this* case, however, as you cannot simply loop through the variadic parameters directly in order to pass them one at a time to `<<`, eg `for (param: vs) { oss << param; }` (although that would be cool if the language could do that). This is especially true if the parameters are different data types (as is the case in this example). So you have to use recursion, so each function call gets specialized to the particular data type being passed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I take that back, pack expansion can work wonders; you don't even need to make a sequence.